# How to iterate over a clojure eduction - without creating a seq?

Tags: clojure, iteration

For the sake of this question, let's assume I created the following eduction.

```
(def xform (map inc))
(def input [1 2 3])
(def educt (eduction xform input))
```

Now I want to pass `educt` to some function that can then do some kind of reduction. The reason I want to pass `educt`, rather than `xform` and `input` is that I don't want to expose `xform` and `input` to that function. If I did, that function could simply do a `(transduce xform f init input)`. But as I don't, that function is left with an eduction that cannot be used with `transduce`.

I know I can e.g. use `doseq` on eductions, but I believe this will create a seq - with all its overhead in terms of object instantiation and usage for caching.

**So how can I efficiently and idiomatically iterate over an eduction?**

As eductions implement `java.lang.Iterable`, this question probably generalizes to:

**How to iterate over a `java.lang.Iterable` without creating a seq?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`reduce`** can be used to do that.

It [works](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L6730) on instances of `IReduceInit`, which [eduction implements](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L7602).